# formatting string in C#

Tags: c#, string

How can I convert this list of strings to comma separated value enclosed within quotes without any escape characters?

```
{"apple", "berry", "cherry"} => well, ""apple", "berry", "cherry""
```

Comment: This is now completely useless.

Comment: What language is this? C#? Javascript, C++?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood you correctly,

```
"\"" + String.Join("\", \"", new string[]{"apple","berry","cherry"}) + "\"";
```

or, alternatively,

```
String.Format("\"{0}\"", String.Join("\", \"", new string[] {"apple","berry","cherry"}));
```

Read more on [System.String.Join(...)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0h8wc12c).

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will do the job

```
var ar = new []{ "apple", "berry", "cherry" };
var separator = "\",\"";
var enclosingTag = "\"";
Console.WriteLine ( enclosingTag + String.Join(separator, ar) + enclosingTag );
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using C#:

```
using System;
string[] arr = new string[] { "apple", "berry", "cherry" };
string sep = "\",\"";
string enclosure = "\"";
string result = enclosure + String.Join(sep, arr) + enclosure;
```